# Notice: Undefined index: #value in element_validate_integer_positive()

Tags: php, drupal, form-api

I'm getting the error `Notice: Undefined index: #value in element_validate_integer_positive() (line 4190 of includes\form.inc)` after clicking the `Upload` or `Remove` of a `managed_file` even though the file is actually being stored in the correct directory.

Here's the relevant snippet:

```
$form['some_image'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Image'),
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#description' => t('The uploaded image will be displayed on this page using the image style choosen below.'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('some_image', ''),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://some_images/',
  );
```

I'm running the instance on XAMPP with PHP 5.3.6. Downgrading to PHP 5.2.9 didn't fix the problem as indicated in the other forums.

When I use Chrome to checkout the ajax request URL, I see the message that is also seen from looking at `file/ajax/image/file/form-wRaEJ-JRPqC7q6BSbp6Ccxi_9X1cpiaBzhwlIs9NFd0` that I found from `/admin/reports/dblog`

> Error message An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size (512 MB) that this server supports.

Note that I'm only uploading a 100kb file.

Line 4190 of `includes/form.inc` is as follows:

```
function element_validate_integer_positive($element, &$form_state) {
  $value = $element['#value'];
  if ($value !== '' && (!is_numeric($value) || intval($value) != $value || $value <= 0)) {
    form_error($element, t('%name must be a positive integer.', array('%name' => $element['#title'])));
  }
}
```

**Update:** It turns out the problem is not just for the `managed_file`, but also for the form itself. Clicking the submit button shows the very same error.

Currently, my `hook_form_validate` is as follows:

```
function mymodule_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {    
}
```

Removing it gives me a Drupal error that says it should be there. I think I'm missing an implementation some other hook, but I have no idea which.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was coming from an entirely different field from the same form whose `#type` incorrectly valued with `numericfield`. I had to remove all my form fields and search which of them was causing the error.

It looks like the `managed_file` fields also trigger the validation for all the other fields in the same form when the `Upload` button is clicked.